# What is the usual gas fee by deploying innicial liquidity to my eth token?

Tags: uniswapv3, liquidity

Wanted to know what gas fees I need to expect when adding initial liquidity to my eth token.
I removed liquidity for about 11 dollar gas. Now I want to add a new tokenpair and set with it a new price but gas fees are about $300 plus by adding only 0.24eth to the liquidity.
Is there a way around? And what I need to calculate minimum to get liquidity added

Answer (score 0):

If the gas estimate is very high, ($300 sounds high with current eth prices), it can be a warning that the transaction will fail.

The amount added doesn't effect the gas required to compute calling the function.
You could avoid some fraction of gas fees by interacting with the pools directly, but it's a slightly advanced method that would likely end up costing more for a one off.

The amount you'll pay is the gas fee * limit used. You can simulate the transaction to see how much it will cost and if it would be successful.

In python, for a simple estimation of current cost in ether to call a method:

```
(w3.eth.gas_price + w3.eth.max_priority_fee) * Contract.functions.method().estimate_gas(tx)
```

If not comfortable to do programmatically, use a service like tenderly.co.
Add the address and abi for the router on the simulation page, then fill in the fields and simulate. 
Note the limit used, then wait for gas price per unit shown on etherscan's gas tracker, to drop to a low enough 'gwei', that you are willing to pay the result of it multiplied by the limit needed.

https://docs.tenderly.co/simulations-and-forks/intro-to-simulations